# What type of machine language do PCs generally run on

Tags: mips, intel, jit, instruction-set, machine-code

I've recently begun researching what it would take to program a JIT compiler. I've been studying on machine language, but I haven't been able to find what type of machine languages most standard PCs run on. I found [this PDF](http://www.cs.umsl.edu/~sanjiv/classes/cs312/lectures/instruct.pdf) which seems to explain a type of ML, but it says it's MIPS, which, after [looking it up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture), seems to be some kind of old, videogame console/router machine language. So, my question is,

**What machine language do most modern personal computers (i.e. laptops, desktops) run on?**

Or, is it indeterminable? Are there many machine languages? Or maybe I'm wrong, and MIPS is standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The machine language used by a given processor is a function of its [instruction-set architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) ("ISA").

Most desktop and laptop computers today running Microsoft Windows use "64-bit" processors implementing the "[x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64)" ISA, such as those in Intel's "Core i5" and "Core i7" processor families.  Commonly referred to as "x64", this is the 64-bit extension (created by AMD) for the original "[IA-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32)" ISA (created by Intel).

Both "IA-32" and "x64" are examples of [Complex Instruction Set Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing) ("CISC") architectures.  On the other hand, [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) is an example of the much simpler [Reduced Instruction Set Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) ("RISC") style of architectures.

When talking about [JIT compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), it is important to distinguish between the ISA of the virtual machine running the byte-code and the ISA of the underlying physical processor.  Most virtual machines are based upon RISC architectures, because of their relative simplicity.  However, most likely this VM-plus-JIT-compiler will be physically running on an x64-compatible CISC processor.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Then how do 32-bit programs run on 64-bit processors? Or do modern computers have _both_ 64-bit and 32-bit processors?

Comment: x64 is an extension of the original IA-32 architectures, and all x64 processors today also support IA-32.

Which of the actual ISA modes actually gets used is a function of which OS you are running.  If you are running, for example, a "64-bit" version of Windows or Linux, then it will make use of the 64-bit capabilities of your x64 processor.  If you are running a "32-bit" OS, then only the IA-32 portion of the processor will be used.

Comment: Ok, -- now I'm looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings. How do I know which instructions computers support?

Comment: If you know for sure that you are dealing with some form of an x64-compatible processor, then you can assume the "core" set of original x86-64 instructions.  (Later versions of x64 added a few new instructions, such as [SSE3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3), but I doubt these minor differences should matter.)  You can certainly always minimalistically assume the core instructions of the original IA-32 architecture!  The exact version of the processor can be determined programmatically using the [CPUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction.

Comment: @YosiMor, I have a doubt, as you said x86-64 is an extension to IA-32, which means IA64 is an extension of IA-32 or??

Comment: @YosiMor, another doubt; Similarly, if x86-64, being extension to IA-32,whant is the bus width of core i5, i7 processors, 32 or 64??

Comment: @nmxprime: [1] The [IA-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA64) instruction-set architecture is TOTALLY different from and unrelated to that of x86-64! [2] The term "bus width" is too vague, and for a CPU it can generally refer to at least the address-bus or data-bus. Also, this is a property that can potentially be different for each specific processor [microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture), even if they belong to the same ISA family.  For data on specific Intel processors you can consult: http://ark.intel.com/ .